# Login Authentication System

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop, input

I am making a python login system for a school project I am proposing, I am having a logic error which I cannot find. The program should allow three login attempts and should display 'correct' when you are logged in, but instead the program runs and when you type in the correct username and password, it prints 'you have entered the wrong password' and loops the program, then when you type in any value, it stops the program and nothing shows up. Could you help me identify the logic error. 
I will be happy to explain the roles of any function :)

```
def logging():
    atmptcount = 0
    usr = input('Please enter your username: ')
    pas = input('Please enter your password: ')
    while atmptcount != 3:
        for line in login:
            log = line.split(',')
            if usr == log[0] and pas == log[1]:
                print('correct')
            elif usr != log[0] and pas != log[1]:
                atmptcount = atmptcount + 1
                print('Sorry you have entered your details incorrectly, please try again')
                logging()
logging()
```

Comment: Try printing out `log[0]` `log[1]` and see what the values are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic here is a bit flawed, I've corrected it slightly - you were on the right lines though!

Firstly, you ask the user for input outside of your `while` loop. This means that every time you loop back, the user isn't getting another chance to input new details.

Secondly, with your `elif` statement, this runs every time a user/pass doesn't match a line in your `login` list. We fix this by only running this code after we've been through the entire file and haven't found a match.

Thirdly, instead of looping back to the start of your while loop if there is no match, you call the function again using `logging()`. This starts a new iteration of the function, and as it will never return anything, you will get stuck in infinite recursion. Instead, we loop back to the start of the while function.

After we've reached attempt 3, I've added a message and a return value. `logging()` now returns `True`, if the user enters a correct user/pass combination within 3 attempts, and `False` otherwise.

Sample code is below.

```
def logging():
    # Set attempt number to 0
    atmptcount = 0

    # Keep asking until max number of attempts is reached
    while atmptcount <= 3:

        # Prompt user for input
        usr = input('Please enter your username: ')
        pas = input('Please enter your password: ')

        # Check through login file
        for line in login:
            log = line.split(',')

            # If details are correct, tell the user and return True
            if usr == log[0] and pas == log[1]:
                print('correct')
                return True

        # If we reached the end of the login file and nothing matched, increase
        # attempts by 1 and inform the user.
        atmptcount = atmptcount + 1
        print('Sorry you have entered your details incorrectly, please try again')

    # If the user has reached the max attempts, inform them and return False
    print('Reached max number of attempts')
    return False
logging()
```